# Replacing nested while loops with vectorization/optimization

Tags: r, loops, optimization, nested-loops

I am trying to code a lineup simulator that basically runs absorbing markov chains a bunch of times in hopes of approaching the "true" average number of runs a lineup would produce. I have looked at about 25 posts on here of people explaining certain types of vectorization and optimization but was not able to work in any of these into my code. Thus, I thought I would ask and see if there was any tips. Thank you!

```
PHLoops <- function(P1,P2,P3,P4,P5,P6,P7,P8,P9,PPH,R,start=1){
    s <- start; path <- NULL; runs <- 0; zz=1;inn=1;gam=1;atbat=1
    while (gam<163){
    while(inn<10){
    s <- start; path <- NULL; 
    while(s<25){
    if(zz==1){
    P=P1
    }
    if(zz==2){
    P=P2
    }
    if(zz==3){
    P=P3
    }
    if(zz==4){
    P=P4
    }
    if(zz==5){
    P=P5
    }
    if(zz==6){
    P=P6
    }
    if(zz==7){
      x3 <- sample(1:100, 1)
      if((atbat>=24)&(table(P7==mat9)[1]>=625)&(atbat<=30)&(x3<=6)){
        P=P7
      }else if((atbat>=25)&(table(P7==mat9)[1]>624)&(atbat<=30)&(x3>=7)){
        P=PPH
      }else if(((atbat>=27)&(table(P8==mat9)[1]>624))){
        P=PPH
      }else{
        P=P7
      }
    }
    if(zz==8){
      x3 <- sample(1:100, 1)
      if((atbat>=25)&(table(P8==mat9)[1]>624)&(atbat<=30)&(x3<=3)){
        P=P8
      }else if((atbat>=26)&(table(P8==mat9)[1]>=625)&(atbat<=32)&(x3>=4)){
        P=PPH
      }else if(((atbat>=27)&(table(P8==mat9)[1]>624))){
        P=PPH
      }else{
        P=P8
      }
    }
    if(zz==9){
        if(((atbat>=27)&(table(P9==mat9)[1]>624))){
        P=PPH
        }
        else{
        P=P9
        }
    }
    s.new <- sample(1:25,1,prob=P[s,])
    path <- c(path,s.new)
    runs <- runs+R[s,s.new]
    s <- s.new
    zz=ifelse(zz==9,1,zz+1)
    atbat=atbat+1
}
inn=inn+1
runs
}
gam=gam+1
atbat=1
inn=1
runs
}
runs
}
```

I then run this function using:

```
RUNS8 <- replicate(1000,PHLoops(mat2,
    mat4,mat5,mat7,mat1,mat8,mat6,mat9,mat3,mat10,R))
```

Where mat 1-10 are 25x25 transition matrices for each individual player. R is a matrix that tells the function how many runs a team gets going from one state to a different state. zz is a variable that corresponds to where we are in the batting order. The 7-9 spots are different because the pitcher does not bat every time he comes up to bat. So basically after 2 full iterations through the order the pitcher will not bat and rather PPH (pitch hitter) will bat. While, the pitcher will hit more often as he gets closer to the top of the order. (that is what x3 is simulating).

Any help would be great and I will continue to read the forums for further tips.

Thank you!

UPDATE (2-11)

Made the changes that people suggested below and the code now looks like this:

```
simulate.half.inning9test <- function(P1,P2,P3,P4,P5,P6,P7,P8,P9,PPH,R,start=1){
    s <- start; path <- NULL; runs <- 0; zz=1;inn=1;gam=1;atbat=1
    p7=(table(P7==mat9)[1]>624)
    p8=(table(P8==mat9)[1]>624)
    p9=(table(P9==mat9)[1]>624)
    order=list(P1,P2,P3,P4,P5,P6,P7,P8,P9)
    while (gam<163){
    x3 <- sample(1:100, 1)
    while(inn<10){
    s <- start; path <- NULL; 
    while(s<25){
    P=order[[zz]]
    if(zz==7){
      if((atbat>=24)&&(p7==TRUE)&&(atbat<=30)&&(x3<=6)){
        P=P7
      }else if((atbat>=25)&&(p7==TRUE)&&(atbat<=30)&&(x3>=7)){
        P=PPH
      }else if(((atbat>=27)&&(p7==TRUE))){
        P=PPH
      }else{
        P=P7
      }
    }
    if(zz==8){
      if((atbat>=25)&&(p8==TRUE)&&(atbat<=30)&&(x3<=3)){
        P=P8
      }else if((atbat>=26)&&(p8==TRUE)&&(atbat<=32)&&(x3>=4)){
        P=PPH
      }else if(((atbat>=27)&&(p8==TRUE))){
        P=PPH
      }else{
        P=P8
      }
    }
    if(zz==9){
        if(((atbat>=27)&&(p9==TRUE))){
        P=PPH
        }
        else{
        P=P9
        }
    }
    s.new <- sample(1:25,1,prob=P[s,])
    runs <- runs+R[s,s.new]
    s <- s.new
    zz=ifelse(zz==9,1,zz+1)
    atbat=atbat+1
}
inn=inn+1
runs
}
gam=gam+1
atbat=1
inn=1
runs
}
runs
}
```

Comment: That type of optimization is really minor. You can usually get much larger speedups by adjusting the algorithm you are using to be more efficient. I don't think vectorization is the issue you have is your code is performing too slowly.

Comment: Any ideas on algorithm speed ups for something that does loop for multiple instances?

Comment: 1) It looks like things like `table(P7==mat9)` should be computed once and for all before the `while` loops. 2) `path <- c(path, s.new)` is a rookie mistake: you should pre-allocate `path` or grow a list. 3) You have a bunch of `if` but only one of them will run so you should use `switch` or a bunch of if/else if/.../else.

Comment: Thank you for your help @flodel ! Those are great suggestions. Question, is if/else if/else faster than a bunch of ifs? I would assume so. Also, are while loops faster or slower than just replicating more times? I could take out the gam<163 and just replicate it 162*x, would that be faster?

Does this type of absorbing markov chain have any hope of going fast?

Comment: 1) You do not need to init x3 before it is needed (((atbat>=24)&(table(P7==mat9)[1]>=625)&(atbat<=30) 2) use shortcut operator (&&, ||)

Comment: Just taking out all of the table(P7==mat9), creating a list, and only calculating x3 once per game took my system time from 4.71 to .17. Now will have to get some more performance but this makes it at least manageable. Reposted my code above in update to showcase all of your guys' help.